# Cosmos DB pricing

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I do not understand the logic of pricing of Cosmos DB. Let's say I have `Provisioned Throughput` type of database. Now the price is measured in `RU/s`. Let's say I run the specific query three times a day. Totally per month I will read the data of the size of `10GBs`. So I will be reading 90 times per month and each read will be `~111 MBs` - let's assume that is `2423 request units`. Does that mean that my cost will be `2423 RU / 100 units * 0.008 * 3 hours * 30 days = $17`? Do I need to make more requests so it would be cheaper? Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. Ask the vendor.

Comment: All of the pricing is fully documented. The pricing is for allocated RU/sec, and really has nothing to do with the number of queries you run. Unfortunately this question is off-topic though, as it's a pricing question.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [`pricing calculator`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=cosmos-db), your pricing of a provisioned throughput of `2500 RU/s` will be `$146.00 = 2500 RU / 100 * 0.008 * 730` where `730` is the hours in a month.

Please note that with provisioned throughput model it doesn't matter how many times you query your container. Once the throughput is provisioned, you will pay for it 24x7 whether you use it or not.

If you think that you will be querying your Cosmos DB occasionally, a better pricing model for you would be [`Serverless`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/serverless) model where you only pay for Cosmos DB resources based on when you actually use it.

More information on difference between `Provisioned Throughput` and `Serverless` model can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/throughput-serverless.